# Are "65k" and "65KB" the same?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

Are "65k" and "65KB" the same?

Comment: You've just walked into a minefield and you don't even know it.

Comment: **[puts on his pink helmet]** Holy war, initiate!

Comment: Am I the only one bothered by the fact that he used 65 instead of 64?  You should always use powers of two, even if it's not necessary, because if you don't it gives programmers the willies.

Comment: This my friend is the exact question that started the Cold War.

Comment: @beska - That is exactly why I hate shopping for hard drives.

Comment: Am I the only one bothered by the fact that he used 65 instead of 66?

Comment: 65,536 bytes = 64 KiB ≈ 66 kB.  Sorry if this is too hard for you programmers to grasp.

Comment: @endolith: sorry, I should have put a smiley on that last comment.  Here you go:  :)

Answer (score 54):

From [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/394/):

[image: I would take 'kibibyte' more seriously if it didn't sound so much like 'Kibbles N Bits'.]

Answer (score 35):

65KB normally means 66560 bytes.  65k means 65000, and says nothing about what it is 65000 of.  If someone says 65k bytes, they might means 65KB...but they're mispeaking if so.  Some people argue for the use of KiB to mean 66560 bytes, since k means 1000 in the metric system.  Everyone ignores them, though.

Note: a lowercase b would mean bit, rather than bytes.  8Kb = 1KB.  When talking about transmission rates, bits are usually used.

Edit: As Joel mentions, hard drive manufacturers often treat the K as meaning 1000.  So hard disk space of 65KB would often mean 65000.  Thumb drives and the like tend to use K as meaning 1024, though.

Comment: 66560?  Perhaps you mean 65536?

Comment: @Greg: no, he doesn't. Multiply 65 times 1024.

Comment: @Greg: No, that would be 64KB.  I know computer nerds prefer to think in powers of 2 but...

Comment: Do notice that in transmission 8Kb does not always equal 1KB. Some bits are used for additional syncronization, error checking, etc. and they are counted too. Usually 8Kb < 1KB.

Comment: @Josip: No, it still equals 1KB, but not all of it is actually used for data.

Comment: You might also want to add that to hard-drive/flash-drive manufacturers, 65KB would indeed mean 65000 bytes.

Answer (score 27):

Probably.

Technically 65k just means 65 thousand (monkeys perhaps?).  You would have to take into account the context.

Comment: Probably is the best answer that can be given w/o more context.

Answer (score 6):

65kB can be interpreted to mean either 65 * 1000 = 65,000 bytes or 60 * 2^10 = 66,560 bytes.

[You can read about all this and kibibytes at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix).

Comment: The word "kibibytes" makes me wince.

Comment: you eventually get used to it.  I winced at first too, yet now I'm glad for the specificity.  I even write KiB sometimes to be explicit.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of data transfer rates - 65k implies 65 kilobits and 65KB implies 65 KiloBytes

Check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units

cheers

Comment: this is my favorite answer.  this is the ONLY answer that actually answers the question correctly.  "implications" are everything, especially amongst people who don't know what they are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

65k is 65,000 of something
65KB is 66,560 bytes (65*1024)

Answer (score 4):

Like most have said, 65KB is 66560, 65k is 65000.  65KB means 66560 BYTES, and 65k is ambiguous.  So they're not the same.

Additionally, since there are a few people equating "8 bits = 1 byte", I thought I'd add a little bit about that.

Transmission rates are usually in bits per second, because the grouping into bytes might not be directly related to the actual transmission clock rate.

Take for instance 9600 baud with RS232 serial ports.  There are always exactly 9600 bits going out per second (+/- maybe a 5% clock tolerance).   However, if those bits are grouped as N-8-1, meaning "no parity, 8 bits, 1 stop bit", then there are 10 bits per byte and so the byte rate is 960 bytes/second maximum.  However, if you have something odd like E-8-2, or "even parity, 8 bits, 2 stop bits" then it's 12 bits per byte, or 800 bytes/second.  The actual bits are going out at *exactly the same rate*, so it only makes sense to talk about the bits/second rate.

So 1 byte might be 8 bits, 9 bits (ie parity), 10 bits (ie N81,E71,N72), 11 bits(ie E81), 12 bits (ie E82), or whatever.  There are lots of combinations of ways with just RS232-style transmission to get very odd byte rates.  If you throw in RS or ECC correction, you could have even more bits per byte.  Then there's 8b/10b, 6b/8b, hamming codes, etc...

Comment: That is a good description why bytes (the 8 bits per byte) are used for describing space on disk, but for transmission rates bits are just about always used instead. If someone says "I bought a 120 gig hard drive" they mean gigabytes with 8-bit bytes. If someone says they have "20 meg broadband" they mean megabits.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte) for Kilobyte:

> It is abbreviated in a number of ways: KB, kB, K and Kbyte.

In other words, they could both be abbreviations for Kilobyte.  However, using only a lowercase 'k' is not a standard abbreviation, but most people will know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

- **kB = kiloByte**
- KB = KelvinByte
- **kb = kilobit**
- Kb = Kelvinbit

**Use the bold ones!** But be aware that some people use 1024 instead of 1000 for k (kilo).

*My opinion on this: kilo = 1000. So the first one who decided to use 1024 made the mistake. If I am not mistaken 1024 was used first by IT engineers. Later they found out (probably some marketing genius) that they can label things using 1000 as kilo and make things look bigger than they actualy are. Since then, you can't be sure which value is used for kilo.*

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, they're both 65 kilobytes (66,560 bytes).

Sometimes the abbreviations are tricky with casing.  If it had been "65Kb", it would have correctly meant kilo***bits***.

Answer (score 0):

A kilobyte (KB) is 1024 bytes.
Kilo stands for 1000.

So, going purely by notation:  (65k = 65,000) != (65KB = 66,560).

However, if you're talking about memory you're probably always going to see KB (even if its written as k).

Generally, KB = k.  [It's all very confusing really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(data)).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the former is not specifying the unit:  65,000 What? So, the two can't really be compared.

However, in general speech then most people mean 65K (note it's normally uppercase) to mean 65 KiloBytes (or 65 * 1024 Bytes).

Note 65Kb usually denotes Kilo*Bits*.

Comment: Except that K is Kelvin, so you should be using k for kilo.

Answer (score 0):

"Officially", 65k is 65,000; however people say 65k all the time, even if the real number is something like 65,123.

Typically 65k means anywhere from 64.00001 to 65.99999998 KiB or sometimes anywhere between 63500 and 64999 bytes ... ie, we aren't all the precise most of the time with sizes of things.  When someone cares to be precise, they will be explicit, or the meaning will be clear from context.

65 KiB means 65 * 1024 bytes. .... unless the person was rounding.  Never trust a number unless you measure it yourself!  ... :)

Hope that helps,

---  Dave

Answer (score -1):

65k may be the same as 65KB, but remember, 65KB is larger than 65Kb.

Case is important, as are units.

Psto, you're right.  This is an absolute minefield!

Comment: The lowercase 'b' has been used for both 'byte' and 'bit'.  Better to avoid ambiguity and use 'B' for byte and 'bit' for bit.  'bit' is already an abbreviation for "binary digit', after all.

kbit/s = 1000 bits per second 
MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes per second

Comment: Ever smacked your thumb with a hammer?  They've been used for that, but it's not the right way to use a hammer.  Just because something has been used for a particular thing it doesn't mean it's right.  This is also why my wife uses a knife to change plugs...

Answer (score -1):

As many said, K is tecnically Kilo, meaning Thousand (of anything) and comes from greek.
But you can assume different units depending on the context.
As data transfer rates are most often measured in bits, K in this context could be assumed to be Kilo Bits.
When talking about data storage, a file's size, etc. K can be assumed to be Kilo Bytes.

Comment: K is the abbreviation for Kelvin, not kilo. k (lowercase) is the abbreviation for kilo.

Comment: @Gordon don't troll here, please. You know we're not talking about anything even remotely related to temperature, the subject under discussion here is memory storage units and your comment doesn't help at all.

Comment: Gordon is right. If you want an accurate answer you need to stay case-sensitive. K is not kilo. K is Kelvin. k is kilo. So a big K is wrong anyway.